# Python: check lists of variable lengths against a fixed "master" list of expected values

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm working with a dictionary that contains key:list pairs.  The lists are of variable lengths as they represent assets accessed by particular users.  ie:

```
{a:[0,3,4],b:[0,1,3,4,5]}
```

I have a list of assets that I would like to check each user against.  ie:

```
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

How can I check each user against the master list, such that I end up with:

```
{a:[1,0,0,1,1,0,0],b:[1,1,0,1,1,1,0]}
```

where for each asset the user has visited, the new list returns 1 and for each they missed, it returns 0.  The new lists should all have the same length of the master list.

Many thanks,
Thain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a comprehension:

```
>>> d = {a: [0,3,4], b: [0,1,3,4,5]}
>>> master = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>> {k: [int(i in v) for i in master] for k,v in d.iteritems()}
{'a': [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0], 'b': [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]}
```